# Reloading android view in a fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, view

I'm using Android Eclipse while working on a project where the user can save and upload notes with images.

I have a fragment which holds a textview and some thumbnail images. The user can add additional images by using the camera and they can remove images by viewing(clicking) an image (in a separate activity) and deleting it.

My problem is with refreshing the layout of the fragment to reflect a deleted image. Currently the following function is being called to deal with this:

```
public ViewGroup removeNoteImageFromView(String location) {
    List<String> imageLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String string : imageLocations) {
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase(location)) {
            break;              
        }
        imageLinks.add(string);
    }

    //REMOVE ALL THE IMAGEVIEWS from the Linear Layout
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
    if (linear.getChildCount() != 0) {
        linear.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        linear.refreshDrawableState();
        linear.postInvalidate();

    }

    imageLocations.addAll(imageLinks);
    //Add them all back from the new array
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    for (String string : imageLinks) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((new File(root +"/saved_images/"+string)).getAbsolutePath());
        addImage(myBitmap);
    }
    return linear;
}
```

All this code does is hide all thumbnails which is called by linear.removeAllViewsInLayout(). However the following two line are what I thought would reload the layout on screen but they appear to have no effect whatsoever.

Please note I have tried linear.invalidate() as well as postInvalidate and still get nothing.

The correct image is deleted from the device as this is dealt with elsewhere so when I go back to this fragment by reselecting it in the menu everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: This code makes little sense since you've added a string from imageLocations to imageLinks i.e imageLinks.add(string); and then readding the same string to imageLocations again imageLocations.addAll(imageLinks); You seem to have skipped clearing the list prior to readding.

Comment: @humblerookie The thing is I'm new to android/java development and this is my first project that has been worked on by a few devs before me so most of the code isn't even mine im afraid :/

Comment: Hey I understand that but, why would you add another string to a List (imagelocations) from the very list(imagelocations) itself.I was reflecting on this logic used by the above code.
Just observe what you are doing with the imageLocation List via the code

Comment: that's fair enough. Only the previous dev can answer that one i suppose haha

Comment: what I implied was you need to do a removeAll() instead of addAll() i.e imageLocations.addAll(imageLinks) to  imageLocations.removeAll(imageLinks) 

and

for (String string : imageLinks)  to  for (String string : imageLocations)

Comment: Oh lol well i've made those changes and nothing seems to have changed. I also removed all code apart from the remove all the imageviews section and that too also seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65755/discussion-between-humblerookie-and-jampez77).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so I finally got it!

I feel a bit stupid as the code works fine but the root path was incorrect so it wasn't finding the images to add back into the view.

Thank you for all the responses and help. Sorry for my newbieness (I've only been properly using Java for a couple of weeks).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
linear.refreshDrawableState();
linear.postInvalidate();
```

With this:

```
linear.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Still nothing i'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // Your code is here...
 // for refresh view use..
 convertView.invalidate();

}
```

Comment: I can't get that to make a difference. I've tried putting all my code from removeNoteImageFromView to this and called it instead but no difference. Is this what i need to be doing or am i being an idiot?